# Merged column doesn't display properly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my first data frame df1

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam |
| 2 | Mam |
| 3 | Dam |

This is my second data frame df2

| ID | Parent ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 |

This is my third dataframe df3

| Parent ID | Location |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | New York |
| 8 | London |
| 9 | San Diego |
| 4 | Mumbai |
| 5 | Pataya |
| 6 | Canberra |

```
df4=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['ID'], how='left')
```

| ID | Game | Parent ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | 4 |
| 2 | Mam | 5 |
| 3 | Dam | 6 |

I want to merge now the df5 which is giving me the invalid result

```
 df5=pd.merge(df4,df3,on=['Parent ID'], how='left')
```

| ID | Game | Parent ID | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | 4 | New york |
| 2 | Mam | 5 | London |
| 3 | Dam | 6 | San Diego |

I am not sure why it is selecting the first values instead of the common ones like the first merge

Comment: Cannot replicate (arguably, changed some code to avoid errors). Can you make sure the code provided is accurate?

Comment: this is actually dummy data for demonstration which I used but yes, the information is correct

Comment: Specifically this line `df5=pd.merge(df4,df3 on=['Parent ID', how='left']` cannot be what you have in your code, it would simply not run.

Comment: In your dummy data `pd.merge()` method is working as expected...instead of `how='left'` don't pass `how` parameter i.e `df5=pd.merge(df4,df3,on=['Parent ID'])`

Comment: sorry it was a typo error  df5=pd.merge(df4,df3 on=['Parent ID'], how='left'). Someone had edited it

Comment: Assuming the missing comma after df3 is there in your code, this works fine with your dummy data (i.e. outputs correct locations in df5)

Comment: I had tried without 'how' before but it was still returning the data the way the df3 dataframe structure. it is simply not taking the common elements. just displaying df3 dataframe

Comment: I have found solution.  If you can help me separate numbers from this, then I know what the problem is.     (123456). I want to separate all the numbers like 123456. etc.   df_3['PA ID']= df_3['PA Name'].str.extract("(\d*\.?\d+)", expand=True)   I am currently using this but is the cause of the problem I guess